# Javascript every href onclick

Tags: javascript, html, href

I am developing an app that stays in the website itself, and I want every link to call a function. I have tried this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="index.php">link</a><br>
<a href="news.php">link 2</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].onclick = function () {
    return false
  }
}
```

What is wrong? It doesn't work.

Comment: What browser? and what is "I can't come out?"

Comment: For one, you have spaces in your tags. Should be `<a>` and `</a>`, not `< a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's not jQuery, you should use the [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) function.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       a[i].onclick = function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are doing plain javascript, use [element].addEventListener("click", function(e){e.preventDefault();return false;}); and not onClick, because you will be overriding all other onClick events

Comment: @japrescott, though it's a good advice, it's not mandatory. anyway, it's his code.

Comment: @japrescott in which case it would be a good idea to also add `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent any parent elements of being notified of the event.

Comment: @AndreiNemes, It depends on what exactly he wants, bubbling is helpful a lot of times.

Comment: @gdoron I think it's safe to assume that if you want to stop a default event from happening altogether, you wouldn't need the parent to know about it either. But yeah, it depends on him.

Comment: @gordon of course its not mandatory, but its stupid if you dont and create potential hours of bug-seeking scenarios for yourself on purpose. I agree though that e.stopPropagation is most often not what you want.
Check out my answer further down that only creates one single function for the problem

Comment: @japrescott, I don't like that attitude, anyway, I've seen a plugin which did it and thus caused a bug. hold your horses and keep discussion clean from "stupid" words.

Comment: @gordon sorry for using such an insulting word as "stupid". but it is what it is; its stupid to create your own pitfalls on purpose. I am here to help and not to collect points. Maybe you should rethink your motivations in giving deprecated and outdated answers to newbies and remaining stubborn about correcting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

edit for pure javascript solution

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (e.nodeName==="A"){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}, false);
```

This will only add one single event to the document and prevent all clicks on anchor elements only.

I removed the old solution because of the comment, that this wasn't a jquery question

Comment: jQuery is great and does all things, but... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: I totally agree with you. Check my updated answer - best one I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `return false`, it does more than you really need. Instead try `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a").forEach(function (e) {
       e.onclick = function (a) {
           doSomething(a);
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```